# Can you make a value transparent in a colorbar when plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

does anyone know of a way to make a certain color transparent when plotting using matplotlib colormaps? I have a difference plot with positive and negative values, and would like the 'zero' days where nothing has changed to be transparent. A solid white won't work because I have a base map underneath that I would like showing in the areas of zero change.

The 'turbo' color map is perfect - if there is a way I can edit the values to make zero transparent.

```py
h=data.plot('Days_Difference', time=-1, ax=ax, colorbar=False, clim=(-10, 10), cmap='turbo')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `set_bad` method of your colormap to set the masked values to transparent(alpha=0)

```py
masked_data = numpy.ma.masked_equal(data, 0) # Mask values at 0

# Create a custom colormap based on 'turbo' colormap
cmap = matplotlib.colormaps["turbo"]
cmap.set_bad(alpha=0)  # Make masked values transparent

h=masked_data.plot('Days_Difference', time=-1, ax=ax, colorbar=False, clim=(-10, 10), cmap=cmap)
```